# Multi level pie/donut chart in kendo

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-chart

I am looking for kendo pie chart multi level.

I already implemented for the bar char for n level series... Similar like that i need to implement for pie char

**Here is the example for multi level bar char example**

[http://jsbin.com/dovefikohu/](http://jsbin.com/dovefikohu/edit?js,output)

Looking for pie/donut chart multi level series using **kendo asp.net mvc**

smiliar like this

[image]

already implement in fusion chart.

http://www.fusioncharts.com/charts/mlpie_4/

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/donut-charts/index

Comment: already i checked, this will "not help" for Multi level pie/dou.... kindly find the attached image...it was very clear, how the graf structure will bee..

Comment: What's wrong with @calinaadi's link? It's a multilevel donut chart as you indicated.

Comment: since i already tried what @calinaadi is suggested, That will not work with donut chat....."how can i use in kendo dono chart with the same one,FYI, i have provide the navigation link..for viewing the chart"

Comment: did you got the solution?

Comment: note yet... Still searching for it.

Comment: @PrasadRaja, Did you find the way to implement this?